# Dynamic Property call giving error (Property [game] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models: Game and Game_Assignment. Game_Assignment tells whose job it is to play a game.

I am trying to count the number of Game_Assignment's that a user has their id on that also have a specific value on the Game model that it relates to. I'll just get into the Models/the code

Game Model Relationship:

```
public function assignments() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Game_Assignment', 'game_id');
}
```

Game_Assignment Relationship:

```
public function game() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Game', 'game_id');
}
```

Where things are going wrong (in a queue job, if that makes a difference)

```
$gamesDue = Game_Assignment::where('statistician_id', $statistician->id)->game->where('stats_done', '!=', 'yes')->count();
```

I have also tried the following two things, neither worked:

```
$gamesDue = Game_Assignment::where('statistician_id', $statistician->id)->game()->where('stats_done', '!=', 'yes')->count();
```

and...

```
$gamesDue = Game_Assignment::where('statistician_id', $defaultStatistician->id)->with(['games' => function($query) {
        $query->where('stats_done', '!=', 'yes');
      }])->count();
```

None of these work, and the first one I showed threw an error:

```
Property [game] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.
```

Anyone have an idea of where I am going wrong? I am using this link as my reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

When using the query builder of your `Game_Assignment` model, you cannot simply switch context to the query builder of `Game`. You can only call `->game()` or `->game` **after** you retrieved one or many model instances of `Game_Assignment` with `first()` or `get()`.

So, in your particular case, you were looking for `whereHas('game', $callback)` (where `$callback` is a function that applies constraints on the foreign table) in order to add a constraint on the foreign table:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$gamesDue = Game_Assignment::query()
    ->where('statistician_id', $statistician->id)
    ->whereHas('game', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('stats_done', '!=', 'yes');
    })
    ->count();
```

*Side note: a column (`stats_done`) that seems to hold a boolean value (`yes/no`) should be of boolean type and not string/varchar.*

Comment: I follow the logic of what you are saying but it is returning 0 when I put your code into use, even though I can clearly see in the DB that it should not be 0

Comment: Maybe explain in words what exactly you want. From the query I suspect: _I want to get the number of game assignments of a specific user where the game stats are not done yet._

Comment: That is correct. I am assuming since you put count() you know that I'd like to return the count, not the objects. If it helps, I can try and show you what is around the code I am working on, try to explain that stuff too, and see if maybe that is what is screwing this up?

Comment: Sorry, of course you are looking for the count. Doesn't really change anything though. Is there, by any chance, also a `stats_done` column in the `game_assignments` table?

Comment: No, I've seen that elsewhere online but sadly that is not the issue hanging this up. game_assignments only has a couple related ID's

Comment: In this case I'm confused, because the query does exactly what you described. Have you tried running a raw SQL query of what you want to count in order to eliminate possible pitfalls on the Laravel side of things?

Comment: Same here for sure. And no, I haven't. In all honesty I may be able to figure the SQL query out that mimics that but I am not sure how I'd write it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198086/discussion-between-namoshek-and-hunter).